# Probability that interval arithmetic estimate of mean covers the true mean of a normal variable?

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, mean, interval-arithmetic

## Background

Suppose there exists a normal variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ where $\mu, \sigma$ are known. Also suppose that you only observe rounded instances $Y = \operatorname{round}(X, d)$ to some fixed number of decimals $d$ to the right of the decimal point. Knowing $d$ allows us to infer that $x_i \in I_i = [y_i - 10^{-d}, y_i + 10^{-d}]$, and compute an estimate of the interval that the mean falls within using [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

$$\bar I = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I_i$$

## Examples

Take for example that $\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$, and $n=200$. We can plot the cumulative mean (CM) of the interval arithmetic estimate of the mean (`CM:IA`), the cumulative rounded (to one decimal place) mean (`CM:round(x,1)`), the cumulative (sample) mean of the variable $X$ (`CM:x`), and the true population mean $\mu$ (`TM`).

[image]

Here is an identical example except for changing $\sigma \leftarrow 10$.

[image]

The above are fairly representative of a few dozen such plots I have generated and examined. These plots agree with an intuition that the larger the standard deviation $\sigma$, the less likely the estimated interval covering the sample mean will also cover the population mean.

## Question

Given that the mean $\mu$, $\sigma$, sample size $n$, and $d$ are known, as described in the first paragraph, what is the probability that the estimated interval containing the sample mean will also cover the population mean?

Comment: I'm sure I don't understand the question, but let me check: the sample mean $\bar X$ has a Normal distribution with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n.$ The interval is $[\bar X - 0.5\times 10^{-d}, \bar X + 0.5\times 10^{-d}].$ The event it contains $\mu$ can also be described as $\bar X\in[\mu-0.5\times 10^{-d},\mu+0.5\times 10^{-d}].$ Its probability can be directly computed from these facts *via* the usual arithmetic for the Normal distribution. What am I missing?